# TSQL Problem - Link Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do quite a straight forward TSQL link table but I am falling at the first hurdle, basically I want a two way link.

For example ....

If Contact 1 adds contact 2, then contact 2 is connected to contact 1 (and vice versa) the idea being that the query recognises they are paired up.

Table Example

```
RelatedDataID  UniqueID   Related_UniqueID  
-------------------------------------------    
1              AA          BB   
2              CC          DD                     
3
```

Users Table

```
UserID  UniqueID   Username
----------------
1        AA       Bob    
2        BB       Fred    
3        CC       Charlie
4        DD       Billy
```

So basically when I run a query With UniqueID "AA" it will return

```
Username     RelatedID
------------------------    
Bob          1    
Fred         1    
Charlie      0
Billy        0
```

But also when I run it on UniqueID "CC" it should return

```
Username   RelatedID
---------------------
Bob        0    
Fred       0    
Charlie    2
Billy      2
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? My current stored procedure seems to only bring back ones that are linked, and not the ones that are not linked. I need it to bring back a full list of all users, but to have the RelatedID come back as either a 0 or the RelatedDataID.

The UniqueID's are GUIDs.

Here my TSQL statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Test
 @CompanyID int,
 @UniqueID varchar(36),
 @PersonTypeID int
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT
  First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS Full_Name,
  ISNULL(RelatedDataID,0) AS RelatedDataID
 FROM
  Users
 LEFT JOIN
  Related_Data
 ON
  Users.UniqueID = Related_Data.UniqueID
 WHERE
  Users.PersonTypeID = @PersonTypeID
 AND
  Users.Deleted = '0'
 AND
  ((ISNULL(Related_Data.UniqueID,'') = '') OR (Related_Data.UniqueID = @UniqueID OR Related_Data.Related_UniqueID = @UniqueID))
```

Comment: If possible provide a more detailed example; why does Bob have a relation for UniqueID=2, when there are no rows for UniqueID=2 ?

Comment: What happens if Bob has multiple relations? E.g., suppose he's related to Fred and Charlie.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have a two way link. An example would be if I passed UniqueID "1" and UniqueID 1 was linked to UniqueID 2, it would show all the contacts, but flag that UniqueID 1 was linked to UniqueID 2 and vice versa. So if I put UniqueID 2, it would get all the contacts, and show that UniqueID 1 was linked (hence RelatedDataID)

Comment: I have attempted based on a hunch WHERE vs JOIN condition. But I admit I still can't make sense of the output even with your latest edit. In uniq=1, why does bob show 1 and charlie show 2??

Comment: You are down the treacherous path of the EAV that had claimed many a young developers. Read here before you venture further: http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx

Comment: Cyberwiki - sorry example update, this should make it clearer?

Comment: @Tech - In the revised first example where you pass 'AA', why does Bob get a value? That would have Bob related to himself.

Comment: @Tech - What would your expected output be if the related table contained (4, 'AA', 'CC')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**UPDATE**) Given that you mentioned in comments that the UniqueId columns are guids and you want a zero to return when no relations, we have to case the guids to varchar. It is also not clear what the expected output should be if the a given user has multiple relations. This query will choose a relation on User.UniqueID = RelatedData.UniqueId over a relation on User.UniqueId = RelatedData.Related_UniqueId but will only return one row per user.

```
Select U.username
    , U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName As Full_Name
, Case 
    When RD.Related_UniqueID Is Not Null Then RD.RelatedDataId
    When RD1.UniqueId Is Not Null Then RD1.RelatedDataId
    Else 0
    End As RelatedID
From Users As U
    Left Join Related_Data As RD
        On RD.UniqueID = U.UniqueId
            And (
                RD.Related_UniqueID = @UniqueId
                Or RD.UniqueId = @UniqueId
                )
    Left Join Related_Data As RD1
        On RD1.Related_UniqueID = U.UniqueId
            And RD1.UniqueID = @UniqueId
Where U.Deleted = '0'
    And U.PersonTypeId = @PersonTypeId
```

Comment: Hi - please note the UniqueID is a varchar(36) (a GUID). This code doesnt seem to work though. An example would be, if in Related_Data, there was a link between UniqueID 'D' and UniqueID 'E', when I passed in 'D' and 'E' it should show that they are linked to each other.

Comment: @Tech - That UniqueId is a guid is a critical piece of information that should be in the OP. Similarly, edge case data should be included in your sample data along with its appropriate sample output.

Comment: @Tech - I've updated my response to account for the fact that the UniqueId columns are guids. However, can you update your post with the edge case you mentioned. Remember that your query is filtering on a specific @UniqueId relation, so please account for that in your sample output with this new data.

Comment: @Tech - I've updated my solution. However, what about cases when a given user has multiple relations (e.g. ('AA','CC') in addition to ('AA','BB')? What happens if there is a primary relation and a secondary relation (e.g. ('AA','BB') and ('DD','AA')?

Comment: Hi Thomas, It's only a two way relationship between the two records. i.e. If you put 'AA' into the SP it would return 'AA','BB' relationship and also 'DD','AA'.

Comment: @Tech - NM. Overlooked that you are always filtering on one specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the UniqueID (filter/where) condition into the LEFT JOIN condition

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Test
 @CompanyID int,
 @UniqueID varchar(36),
 @PersonTypeID int
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT
  First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS Full_Name,
  ISNULL(RelatedDataID,0) AS RelatedDataID
 FROM
  Users
 LEFT JOIN
  Related_Data
 ON
  Users.UniqueID = Related_Data.UniqueID
 AND
  ((ISNULL(Related_Data.UniqueID,'') = '') OR (Related_Data.UniqueID = @UniqueID OR Related_Data.Related_UniqueID = @UniqueID))
 WHERE
  Users.PersonTypeID = @PersonTypeID
 AND
  Users.Deleted = '0'
END
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter here, since `'' = '' OR null = 1` evaluates to `true or unknown` which evaluates to true

Comment: @Andomar - have you considered where it manages to join to RelatedData, so the ISNULL fizzes, AND all available joined records do not fit @UniqueID? that's why the records are being removed by the WHERE filter

Comment: Just a side note: it should show ALL records, but the RelatedDataID should show if there is any relation between the two ID's.

Comment: You're right, I was looking only at the case where the join didn't succeed.